# How to write "IDs of persons" without using "of"?

Tags: grammar

I never know how to write this correctly. I can think of several ways to write it but which is the right one?

- person IDs
- persons IDs
- persons' IDs

Comment: Isn't there only one ID per person?

Comment: How about 'personal identification'?

Comment: @MorganFR yes, one ID per person but what difference does it make?

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence please?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Example sentence: In the club I am responsible for checking persons IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"In the club I am responsible for checking people's ID".*

Or, *"In the club I am responsible for checking IDs"*.  It's only people that have an ID in this context, so if you say "IDs" (note the plural, which has moved from "people" to "ID", since we don't have "people" in the sentence any more), its obvious what kind of ID you're talking about.

EDIT, re vehicles and wheels

a) "This vehicle's wheel is flat" (1 vehicle, 1 wheel)

b) "This vehicle's wheels are flat" (1 vehicle, many wheels)

c) "These vehicles' wheels are flat" (many vehicle, many wheels)

d) "These vehicles' windscreens are broken" (many vehicle, many windscreens, but only one windscreen per vehicle)

Notes:

1) in c & d, the use of an apostrophe changes from the "singular possessive", "vehicle's" meaning "belonging to the vehicle", seen in a & b, to the "plural possessive", which catches a lot of people out: the apostrophe goes to after the word, signifying that there are lots of vehicles and we're talking about things that belong to *each of them*.

2) Grammatically, there's no clear way to distinguish between c) "many vehicles, many wheels per vehicle" and d) "many vehicles, one windscreen per vehicle", since in both cases we're talking about multiple wheels/windscreens.  So, this would rely on the listener's knowledge in order to fully comprehend the difference.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This makes sense. In order to understand better how English works can I bother you with another question? Let's change "person" and "ID" to "vehicle" and "wheels". Are there sentences where you would use combination "vehicles wheels" or "vehicles' wheels"? Do these word combinations make sense at all?

Comment: @Egidijus: Please avoid to hide new questions in comments. Their function is to clarify or improve a question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

The grammaticaly correct form would be:

persons' ID

because there are many persons and each has one ID.
But this sound awkward because we know that there are many IDs.

Consequently I prefer the use of an adjective to avoid it:

personal IDs